# How to remove padding for mobile devices on WordPress

Tags: css, wordpress

I'm new to WordPress and CSS; currently creating a WordPress site and on the last stretch. I need to figure out a way to override the current padding on desktop and laptop sized browsers, as the elements are stuck in the middle with padding on either side on mobile devices.

I've tried to create my own CSS but it's not working (im rubbish) so I'm hoping some experts can help. I tried this below-

```
@media all and (max-width : 780px) {
.column{
    padding-left:0px;
    padding-right:0px;
}
}
```

The webpage I'm testing it on is https://www.xordium.co.uk/your-cloud-journey/

Thanks!

Comment: Not much to go on off. But the class used in your css is never used in your website.

Comment: i didnt see any class `column` in website

Comment: maybe you men to this class `wpb_column`

Comment: Just tried it with `@media all and (max-width : 780px) {
.wpb_column{
    padding-left:0px;
    padding-right:0px;
}
}
Still nothing :(

Comment: can you tell me what class do you want to change

Answer (score 1):

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    .vc_custom_1528804063483 {
        padding-left: 20px !important;
    }
}
```

simply put this in your style.css file with the width you have set your width as i write 600 for example.

Hope this will work for you.

Comment: Thats it! That's sorted the first text element. Any way to re-write it to cover all elements on the page? Every page bar the home page follows the same template with the same padding on either side to keep every page flush.

Comment: they just ask how to remove the padding in mobile device, they did not ask to remove padding for my element so i can simple tell them the way her removed the padding.